# Change the font size relatively to the div wrapper

Tags: html, css, fonts

I put the div which can change the size by `%`.

In this case in upper square, font size is OK.

but lowwer square font looks smaller.

Is there any good practice to adjst the font size according to the div size??

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;">
<div style="background-color:grey;width:100%;height:100%;">
<p>5</p>
</div>


<div style="width:100px;height:100px;">
<div style="background-color:grey;width:200%;height:200%;">
<p>5</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Comment: You can check this https://dzone.com/articles/css-relative-font-size

Comment: I tried `font-size: 100%` but it just depends on the browser default(16), I want to change relatively to the div wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

you can change font size in div this way `font-size: 150%;`

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;">
<div style="background-color:grey;width:100%;height:100%;">
<p>5</p>
</div>


<div style="width:100px;height:100px;">
<div style="background-color:grey;width:200%;height:200%; font-size: 150%;">
<p>5</p>
</div>
</div>
```